# How insert json file in multiple tables using java?

Tags: java, mysql, json, twitter

I am a beginner with json formatting and I will appreciate any help.
I have a JSON file containing 10.000 tweets from a Twitter db.

I create empty 5 table in a DB, each one of them has specific information like user info, tweet info, etc.  I want to insert this data from the JSON file to specific columns in any table using Java so I can do searches to retrieve specific tweets based on conditions.

I have code to connect the database with the Java class and read the external file but it inserts it in one column, how can i divide it up?

---

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class InsertTextFileToMySQL {

  public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/db_Twitter";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "root";

    Class.forName(driver);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    return conn;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    String id = "001";
    String fileName = "fileName.txt";
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
      conn = getConnection();
      conn.setAutoCommit(false);
      File file = new File(fileName);
      fis = new FileInputStream(file);
      pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into DataFiles(id, fileName, fileBody) values (?, ?, ?)");
      pstmt.setString(1, id);
      pstmt.setString(2, fileName);
      pstmt.setAsciiStream(3, fis, (int) file.length());
      pstmt.executeUpdate();
      conn.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      pstmt.close();
      fis.close();
      conn.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Again, this code is inserting the entire file in one column.

Comment: Can you show the code with which you are having a problem?

Comment: So, from looking at your code, it looks like you are insert your data into three columns, an id, the filename, and the third column is the entire text of the input file.  

You say you want to divide the file text up, but how do you want to divide it up?  Without knowing anything about the file structure, it's hard to help you design a database schema.

Comment: well it's normal...you have to parse your file; other approach would be.....use some JSON library in order to create Java bjects from JSON and then work directly with the created object (you may use jackson marshaller, GSON or other)

Comment: 'azurefrog' in the code i try simple example to understand the idea , i know the file structure and create the table based on it ,
'angelo immediata' if you have good source for parsing the json it will be very helpful , i look up for one that explain clearly but couldn't quit understand.

Comment: i meant reference not source .. sorry english is not my first language